# IBM Worklight - What should I deploy after changing or adding iOS push certificate?

Tags: deployment, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on an IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 project. I configured push notifications for iOS before that my Application is already deployed in the server.

My question is: What should I deploy again to get the push notification certificate (the .p12 certificate file) on the server.
Should I just deploy the iPhone .wlapp file? or should I also deploy a newer version of the .war file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to re-deploy the .wlapp file, which contains the deployment data for the server. In this case, the .p12 certificate required for push notifications.

Comment: In this case, The new file .p12 will only be deployed on server, doesn't it required to be copied to the client device as well?  If that's true do we also need to deploy the App to App Store? Or Direct update will copy the new file to the client device?

Comment: It's not needed on the client.

Comment: if I deploy new .wlapp to the server, technically it will be the new build with the same code and new.p12  file, will user still get the direct update? What if I change it directly on the server, I know where these packaged are deployed on the server, I can just replace it there. What would u suggest?