# ios: worklight apns certificate location on liberty server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I was able to run the Push Notifications for my **local worklight server**. 
However now I want to configure it for my **remote Liberty server**. 
From all the documentation available I know I need to copy the **apns-certificate-sandbox.p12** certificate to my server.
 
But what location should the certificate be in? Also do we need to specify the location of the certificate and the pushSender password in config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 file is part of the .wlapp file that you deploy via Worklight Console.
2. The pushSender value is entered in application-descriptor.xml

On build time, these files and values are stored and the .wlapp file and the .war file.
These are artifacts that you deploy in your remote application server.

There is nothing else you need to modify or configure other than deploy them.

Related question: [IBM Worklight - What should I deploy after changing or adding iOS push certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750331/ibm-worklight-what-should-i-deploy-after-changing-or-adding-ios-push-certifica)

Comment: Oh Thanks Idan for the clarification. There might be some other issue which I need to debug  as even though I am subscribed successfully. I dont receive any notifications. Anyways thanks alot.